# Post on a Facebook page wall as Page name from Application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

All,
I've got a page that I'm an admin for on Facebook and I've also got an application for the page. I'm trying to allow my application to post offline messages to my wall for I can't figure out how to give my application the permissions needed in order to do that. I did find the following URL:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=$id&client_secret=$secret&redirect_uri=$uri&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,read_stream,manage_pages&response_type=token

Can I just put this directly into my browser? I updated the ID and the secret but I'm also not sure what to put into the uri? Does this give me a permanaent token that I can always use?

Any help you can give me is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to get an application access token to post as an application.  You will need to query Graph API's `me/accounts` and find the app in that list. You will also see a different access token assigned to that app.  You then can use that token to post as that app.

See also: [Post to Facebook application page as APPLICATION user](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4530177/post-to-facebook-application-page-as-application-user)  Remember pages and apps are in the same category under the `me/accounts`

```
$result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");
foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
    if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
        $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
        break;
    }
}
$args = array(
    'access_token'  => $page_access_token,
    'message'       => "I'm a Page!"
);
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
```

Comment: thanks for the info. If I get the access token would I have the correct permissions to post to that page then?

Comment: The access token of the page administrator you used to get `me/accounts` needs to have `publish_stream`.

Comment: if it doesn't have the publish_stream how can I make sure that I give the application the correct permissions?

Comment: Ensure you ask the admin for those permissions when you ask him to authenticate you app.  If you don't know what he has, you can call https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ to see what he has for his access token.  If he's missing anything, then send him to login with the proper "scope" (aka permissions list)